# Interacting with already opened browser using HP LeanFT

Tags: java, leanft

I have to interact with already an opened browser and perform few clicks, Page navigation and read text from form controls. Can LeanFT has the capability to do so?

Comment: Yes, it does. Browser.Attach

Comment: @Adelin this should be an answer

Comment: @Motti but by answering I feel like I'm encouraging such poor questions, answers to which are a matter of checking LeanFT's official capabilities.

Comment: @Adelin, on the one hand you're right, on the other hand by answering such a question the answer is now googleable so the next person searching for this will find it more easily.

Comment: @Motti ok - I couldn't just post an answer stating such obvious feature, so I generalized a bit...

Comment: @Adelin I applaud your integrity, good answer too.

Answer (score 1):

LeanFT can do that, and then some...

Basically, for LeanFT, almost anything can be discovered and interacted with. They do that via what they call an element `Description`.

It understands native technologies like Java, WPF, WinForms, Powerbuilder, Mobile, etc. and, obviously, Web.

In your case, you'd have to work with `com.hp.lft.web` package, which contains everything needed to discover anything web related, be it browsers, buttons, media elements, etc.

And, as already mentioned, you need to describe those elements via a description.

The parent element, the `browser`, can be reached in 3 ways, all by making use of the [`BrowserFactory` class](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.51/JavaSDKReference/index.html#JavaSDKReference/com/hp/lft/sdk/web/BrowserFactory.html):

- launching a browser: `BrowserFactory.launch` with the type of browser to launch
- attaching to an already opened browser: `BrowserFactory.attach` with a description
- getting all opened browsers: `BrowserFactory.getAllOpenBrowser` with a description

All these methods will return instances of `Browser`, which have ways to further control a browser.

You can find samples of these methods in [LeanFT's official documentation](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.51/JavaSDKReference/index.html#CodeSamples_Java/codeex_Web.htm).
For visibility, I'll post the relevant `attach` sample:

```
Browser aboutTab = BrowserFactory.attach(new BrowserDescription.Builder().title("Cruises: Mercury Tours").build());
```